# Impact of setAllowedFields and setDisallowedFields methods in DataBinder in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My question is very simple. If I do a `setAllowFields()`, does automatically Spring disallow the others ?

Same question, if I use `setDisallowFields()`, does this allow other fields ?

I think no, but, does anybody have experienced something with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDoc of [`setAllowedFields`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setAllowedFields-java.lang.String...-):

> *"Register fields that should be allowed for binding. Default is all fields. Restrict this for example to avoid unwanted modifications by
>   malicious users when binding HTTP request parameters."*

Which means that by default all fields are allowed. If you don't want to allow all fields, then you can specify the allowed fields in this method.

Similarly for the [`setDisallowedFields`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setDisallowedFields-java.lang.String...-):

> *"Register fields that should not be allowed for binding. Default is none. Mark fields as disallowed for example to avoid unwanted
>   modifications by malicious users when binding HTTP request
>   parameters."*

Which means that by default no field is disallowed. If you want to disallow some of the fields, then you can specify the disallowed fields in this method.

---

So the answer to your question is that `setAllowedFields()` will automatically disallow the non-specified fields, but `setDisallowedFields()` will not automatically allow the non-specified fields (unless you didn't include them in `setAllowedFields()` too).

To support my answer, let me include the Spring's implementation of [`isAllowed`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#isAllowed-java.lang.String-):

```
protected boolean isAllowed(String field) {
    String[] allowed = getAllowedFields();
    String[] disallowed = getDisallowedFields();
    return ((ObjectUtils.isEmpty(allowed) || PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch(allowed, field)) &&
            (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(disallowed) || !PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch(disallowed, field)));
}
```

You can clearly see that if a field is present in `allowedFields` and not present in `disallowedFields` only then it will be allowed. Otherwise, it won't be allowed.

Comment: Thanks @mushif-ali-nawaz. This is what I expected, but need to have some confirmation (really, I did not read the source implementation of spring by a lack of time)

Comment: @SPoint you're welcome. You should always read JavaDoc and implementation if you have confusion. It helps me a lot too!